# Remove items from list if they are within a given range

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, optimization

I want to remove every item from a sorted list, when it is within 100 seconds from one of the previous events. Example:

```
event_list = [3, 10, 12, 140, 140, 150, 300]
filtered_event_list = [3, 140, 300]
```

I have the following piece of code that seems to work. But it does not remove an item that has the same time as the previous one. Another problem Ihave is that it is not very pythonic since I need an additional placeholder for true/false or 0/1 to store my result before I start removing the items that are within 100 seconds.

```
downCycles = 100
event_list = [[3, 0], [10, 0], [12, 0], [140, 0], [140, 0], [150, 0], [300, 0]]

for e_idx, event in enumerate(event_list):

if e_idx > 0:

    prev_idx = e_idx - 1

    while event[0] - event_list[prev_idx][0] < downCycles and prev_idx >= 0:

        event[1]  = event[0] - event_list[prev_idx][0]
        prev_idx -= 1

filtered_event_list = [e for e in event_list if e[1] == 0]
# filtered_event_list = [[3, 0], [140, 0], [140, 0], [300, 0], [800, 0]]
```

Has anybody an idea for removing the second 140 in this example?
Has anybody a better way to write this piece of code?

Thanks 
Regards
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a generator which contains the items.

```
def removeCloseItems(items, itemDistance):
    if items:
        lastOutput = items[0]
        yield items[0]
        for currentItem in items[1:]:
            if ((currentItem - lastOutput) > itemDistance):
                lastOutput = currentItem
                yield currentItem
```

Sample usage:

```
In [79]: [x for x in removeCloseItems ([3, 10, 12, 140, 140, 150, 300], 100)]
Out[79]: [3, 140, 300]
```

This assumes that when you say "within 100 from one of the previous items", you mean one of the previous *output* items. What should the output be for this:

```
[x for x in removeCloseItems([1, 100, 102], 100)
```

Do you want `[1, 102]`, or `[1]`?

The latter would be generated with this code:

```
def removeCloseItems(items, howFar):
    if items:
        lastItem = items[0]
        yield items[0]
        for currentItem in items[1:]:
            lastItem = currentItem
            if ((currentItem - lastItem) > howFar):
                yield currentItem
```

Comment: Thank you zck. Your Option one is exactly what I was looking for. Also thanks for option 2 which is also useful. Michael

Answer (score 2):

you can try this .just try to check the difference of first element with next element

```
event_list = [3, 10, 12, 140, 140, 150, 300]
new_list=[event_list[0]]+

for element in event_list[1:]:
    if abs(new_list[-1]-element)>=100:
       new_list.append(element)
print new_list
```

seeing below answer if you want to make genric method

```
def elapsed_list(items,time):
    new_list=[items[0]]

    for element in items[1:]:
        if abs(new_list[-1]-element)>=time:
           new_list.append(element)
    return new_list


print elapsed_list(event_list,10)
#output [3, 140, 150, 300]

print elapsed_list(event_list,100)
#output [3, 140, 300]

print elapsed_list(event_list,200)
#output [3, 300]
```

explantion how i acheived

1. the logic we need to take difference between the first and the element next
2. so i took another list which takes first element and compute the difference if difference is more than 100. append it to new_list
3. now perfform same with the newly appended element get by `new_list[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import tee

downCycles = 100
event_list = [3, 10, 12, 140, 140, 150, 300]
left, right = tee(event_list)
[next(right)] + [i for i in right if i > next(left) + downCycles]
```

outputs:

```
[3, 140, 300]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is:

```
event_list = [3, 10, 12, 140, 140, 150, 300]    
filtered_lst = [event_list[0]]
filtered_lst +=  [j for (i, j) in zip(event_list[:-1], event_list[1:]) if j-i >100]
```

Now

```
filtered_lst == [3, 140, 300]
```